# What triggers code first migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

How does the command Enable-Migration know whether to generate the migration code files?

I have the following in a project using the standard MVC 5 template in Visual Studio:

```
public class UsersContext : IdentityDbContext<ExtendedUser>
{
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public UsersContext() : base() { }

    public UsersContext(string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString) { }
}

public class Log
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I run Enable-Migrations, the Migrations folder is created but there is only the Configuration.cs file.  There is no code generated to handle the creation of the Logs table.

A second related question is: do I have to run Add-Migration every time there are model changes after the previous Add-Migration was run?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `Enable-Migrations`, it searches the project for any DBContexts and configures that project to use migrations.

**Do I have to run Add-Migration every time there are model changes after the previous Add-Migration was run?**

Yes. Running `Add-Mingration ...` creates files that details your model changes.

Running `Update-Database` pushes your changes to the database. `Update-Database -Script` *(before running just update-database)* generates an SQL script of your model changes.

After you update the database, if you make more model changes, you would add another migration. And the cycle goes on...

See [Tips for Entity Framework Migrations](http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding "...it searches the project for any DBContexts..." would the `IdentityDbContext<ExtendedUser>` in my code above qualify as a DBContext?

Answer (score 1):

**Take note that Enable-Migrations is *not* the same as Automatic migrations.**

Automatic migrations will, if enabled, automatically create and run your migration scripts during runtime, which means that you do not need to run the "add-migrations" and "update-database" commands manually every time your model is updated.

Comment: Don't you still need to call the add-migration?

Comment: @Terry Not with automatic migrations. The migration is generated on the fly at run time, applied and discarded. No migration file is stored. It would be something like running `Add-Migration`, running `Update-Database`, and finally deleting the migration file you just created (probably with different effects on the migrations history table contents, but you get the idea).